# Delete an item from firebase real-time database in an angular web app

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I’ve been working on this project where I’m trying to remove a specific object/item from firebase’s real-time database. But the problem is once I click to remove a specific item the whole list of objects/items is removed from firebase.

Basically I have my service file containing the delete method which is.

```
DeleteItem(item: Item) {
    Return this itemRef.remove(item.$id);
}
```

And in the item.component.ts I have:

```
RemoveItem(item: Item) {
    This.itemService.deleteItem(item );
}
```

In the html.component I am using ngfor to display all items from firebase with a button to delete a specific item and also a button for updating items which actually works.

Currently, I’m using the angularFireDatabase and angularFireModule (@angular/fire/database). ItemRef is the path.

Also I tried the following in the item.component.ts: (it didn’t work though)

```
RemoveItem(item: Item) {
    This.itemService.deleteItem(item).then(res => {
    This.items = this.items.filter(t => t.$id === item.$id);
    });
}
```

I also tried !== in place of ===, since that’s what the source stated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

More of an update on what I've tried so far.

```
DeleteItem(item: Item) {
    // let ids = `/item/ + {item.$id}`;
    // return this.itemRef.remove(task);
    // return this.itemRef.remove(`/users/{item.$id}`);
    // return this.itemRef.remove(task.$id);
    // return this.db.list('/item/' + item.$id).remove();
    // let id = null;
    // return this.itemRef.update(item.$id, id);
    return this.db.list('/item/').update(item.$id, null);
    // this.taskRef.update({item: null});
  }
```

None of them worked though. I.ve been looking npm for any information on @angular/fire/database but couldn't get any farther then @angular/fire

Comment: If you're using the Firebase Realtime Database, why did you also tag the question with Cloud Firestore?

Comment: I was hoping even this with firestore experience may have worked with real-time database. But understand how it differs. Though I manage to get it to work with firestore. I’m still trying to get the real-time database to function.

Comment: What isn't working when you do it like this sample in the docs? https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#removing-items-from-the-list `db.list('items').remove('key-of-some-data')` Is there an error? What gets sent to the database on the wire?

Comment: I realized once I remove the $ from the id. In item class. it worked

Comment: Good to hear! Thanks for the update Gambit.